# When writing generic code for smart pointers and pointers, how to get the simple pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

When I want to implement a function:

```
template <typename TIterator>
void doSomething(TIterator begin, TIterator end);
```

to be able to work with both:

```
std::vector<Widget*>
```

and

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>
```

how should I access the underlying pointer? For some reason `std::shared_ptr<Widget>` is not implicitly convertible to `Widget*` and I have to use the `get()` function. This way, the code does not work for `std::vector<Widget*>` since `Widget*` has no `get()` function.

What I do is this:

```
void functionAcceptingPointer(Widget* widget);

template <typename TIterator>
void doSomething(TIterator begin, TIterator end);
{
    std::map<double, decltype(&(**begin))> map;
    ...
    auto firstPointer = &(**begin);
    ...
    functionAcceptingPointer(&(**begin));
    ....
}
```

That is use the double dereference `*` followed by the `&` operator, whenever I need an ordinary pointer.

It does the job, but I am curious if there is some more readable, generally used way to do this and if there are some things that can come back to haunt me after I fill my code with ugly stuff like `&(**begin)`

Comment: You can define template function getptr(T ptr) { return &(**ptr); } and use it everywhere to make code clearer.

Comment: "For some reason std::shared_ptr<Widget> is not implicitly convertible to Widget*" - can't understand why - [shared_ptr->](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*)

Comment: @borisbn: That is `operator*`, which returns a `Widget&`-not a pointer.

Comment: There are 2 operators in that page. The second is `->`

Comment: "For some reason" For good reason! To implicitly treat a smart pointer as a dumb pointer could have painful consequences: `delete mysmartptr; /* no errors!? */`

Comment: Sorry, I wad missed `functionAcceptingPointer`

Comment: @GManNickG good note. Unfortunally `const` can't help, because it doesn't prevent from `delete`. IMHO, it's C++'s omission

Comment: @borisbn: What they did to address the issue was make the conversion from `std::shared_ptr<Widget>` to `Widget*` _explicit_.  I see no issue here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what I do to solve this problem:

```
#include <memory>

template <class T>
inline
T*
to_raw_pointer(T* p) noexcept
{
    return p;
}

template <class Pointer>
inline
typename std::pointer_traits<typename std::remove_reference<Pointer>::type>::element_type*
to_raw_pointer(Pointer&& p) noexcept
{
    return ::to_raw_pointer(p.operator->());
}
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p1(new int(1));
    int* r1 = to_raw_pointer(p1);
    int* p2 = new int(2);
    int* r2 = to_raw_pointer(p2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I interpret it right you did a partial template specialization and the first definition gets called on normal pointers and the second one on smart pointers. Right?

Comment: Right.  As long as your smart pointer implements `operator->()` and conforms to `pointer_traits`, you're good to go.  And `pointer_traits` was designed so that most smart pointers would conform even if by accident.  This design will even handle `std::unique_ptr<T, D>` when `D::pointer` is itself a smart pointer.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: I'd take the smart pointer by reference, which disallows calling this on temporaries.  Which is good, because (A) your code currently doesn't work with `unique_ptr`, and (B) `to_raw_pointer` might _release_ the pointed at object as it returns if passed a sole-owning temporary.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Good suggestion.  I used an rvalue reference so that I can accept either lvalues or rvalues without needing to make a copy or take ownership.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: I think disallowing rvalues would be a good idea.  If a function returns a smart pointer, and one passes that to this function, that would _guarantee_ that the smart pointer goes out of scope when this function returns, probably releasing said resources.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I surveyed my uses of this function and I sometimes need it to accept rvalues.  Here is a copy/paste from some of my code: `__alloc_traits::construct(__alloc(), _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(__begin_-1), _VSTD::move(__x));`.  In this example `__begin_` **may** be a smart pointer, or a real pointer, and the expression `__begin_-1` is almost certainly going to be an rvalue.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Subtracting `1` from a `shared_ptr` makes no sense, what you have looks very much like an _iterator_, which is a very different use-case than the OP discussed.  I'm not certain a `to_raw_pointer` is a good idea when dealing with iterators.  Isn't the point of iterators to abstract away pointers?

Comment: @HowardHinnant: I just realized who you were: I don't think I'm going to "win" this debate.  I think you'll end up showing me some magic trick or use-case I never thought of.  But for now I still hold that accepting rvalues here is not good.  Or maybe a different function name for the two different use-cases?

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Well instead of "winning", maybe we can settle for a mutually beneficial transfer of knowledge. :-)  In my use case `__begin_` has type `std::allocator_traits<A>::pointer` where `A` is a potentially user-supplied allocator.  The author of `A` can define (or default) `A::pointer` to be a real pointer, or can define it to be a smart pointer satisfying the requirements of NullablePointer (17.6.3.3). In this use case, the smart pointer does not own the pointee. Your suggestion to not pass by value is a good one to widen the use case to owning pointers. So I've definitely benefitted!

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Regarding the first comment: You said "Right.", but I would read your code as "just" two overloaded function, not a partial template specialization. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DanielFrey:  No, you're not missing something.  You are correct.

Answer (score 3):

To increase the readability, you can create your own wrapper to dereference any (smart) pointer:

```
template<typename T> auto raw_deref(T t) -> decltype( &**t ) { return &**t; }
```

which would turn your code into

```
template <typename TIterator>
void doSomething(TIterator begin, TIterator end)
{
    std::map<double, decltype(raw_deref(begin))> map;
    ...
    auto firstPointer = raw_deref(begin);
    ...
    functionAcceptingPointer(raw_deref(begin));
    ....
}
```

and of course you could think of a better name than `raw_deref` :)

Comment: Beware of the case that `decltype(**t)` has an overloaded `operator&()` that doesn't return a real pointer.  For example a `bit_reference` class that when you take the address of it, returns the type `bit_pointer`.

Comment: There are limitations for sure, also if some home-made smart-pointer class returns funny stuff from `operator*`. I hope that the OP is aware of this as his code would suffer from the same problem and so I was just trying to make the code more readable and expressive.